# How to Limit the access of User? 

Tags: asp.net

I have a new  in using asp.net, I have a problem regarding on how I will limit the access of the cashier. I use login on asp.net toolbox and a create user wizard. I don't have any idea about User Roles. What I did is that after I create a user you will identify your self if you are a Admin or a cashier then it will jump to login. My problem is that whenever I create user for cashier it will go to pos.aspx. and if he/she is an admin will go to ATHENA.ASPX Can anyone tell me about that matter? Thanks in advance :D

```
 <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" AllowReturn="False" 
            OnActivate="BuildRoleList"              
            OnDeactivate="AssignUserToRoles">
 <p>
Select Your Role:
</p>
<asp:ListBox ID="AllRoles" runat="server" >
</asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry if I misunderstood your question but you state:

> My problem is that whenever I create user for cashier it will go to
>   pos.aspx

You might want to look into the `LoginCreatedUser` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.logincreateduser.aspx

The default is true, so once you've created a user with this wizard, it logs them in automatically. I've struggled with this in the past, when after creating a new user, odd things happen - because you're now logged in as that new user and not the admin :)

If it's an admin-type function to create a user, then you will want to set that to `false` so that it creates the user but doesn't then login this user.

> I don't have any idea about User Roles

If you want to limit access to parts of your site based on role, then you need to familiarise yourself with user roles - there are plenty of examples at all levels from  [a quick Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+roles+overview)